# Need help with this expression's meaning ロマンはあります

Tags: grammar, meaning, expressions, japanese-to-english, conversations

[image]

「ロマンはありますけど、でもやっぱり気になりますね」
Hope someone can explains to me the meaning of this expression in this sentence. My guess : "Though your reason sounds very romantic (?), but i'm still curious about the real reason you know ?"

Context: There's a rumor in the town, that he's the  local's hero who just broke a hard layer of rocks which blocked the hot spring underground, caused a footbath tourist attraction site stay dried/ deserted for years. Now MC had revived that footbath tourist site, and he became the hot topic of the town (previously he also jumped off a bridge to save a dog from drowning)

MC don't want this, (because actually he didn't do anything, it was his childhood friend who used a karate heel-drop kick to broke the hard rocks underground, and she's the real hero who made the hot spring sprung up again. But then she leaved MC to deal with the journalist+ reporters, so people thought MC is the hero in this story :D) so he decided to hide inside a coffee shop nearby, to avoid the public's eyes.

But in that coffee shop, a waitress still recognized him. She asked MC about the reason why he can break that hard layer of rocks underground, because she said even with heavy machines no one can break those hard rocks.

満留(Waitress)「って、あれ？　あなた、もしかして……」

賢人(MC)「え、何ですか？」

満留「うん、やっぱり！　『空飛ぶ足湯の英雄』さん、ですよね！？」

賢人「…………」

賢人（なに？　俺ってもうそんなに噂になってるの？）

知らない人が自分を知っているというのは、正直怖い。

賢人「ま、まあ今じゃそういうことになってるらしいですね……」

満留「わあ～ッ！　すごいですね！　さっきから常連のお客さん、みんなあなたの話してますよ！」

賢人「あははは……ど、どうも」

訂正、こんな美人が褒めてくれるならちっとも悪い気はしない。

満留「でも見た感じ普通の学生さんだし……」

満留「あの橋から飛び降りたっていうのも信じられない話ですけど」

満留「足湯なんて、どうやって掘り起こしたんですか？

重機でもお手上げ状態だったはずなのに」

賢人「それはなんて言うか、秘密ということで……」

満留「ムムム……。謎のヒーローってことですか」

**満留「ロマンはありますけど、でもやっぱり気になりますね」**

賢人（じろじろ見られると緊張するな……）

Comment: ロマン is a vague word, but this ロマンはあります means something like "It sounds exciting and stirs up my imagination" or "It stirs up a sense of adventure". It has absolutely nothing to do with romance in the sense of love.